# Complex analysis - branch cuts

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

a) Consider $f(z)=z^{-2i}$ with a branch cut along the negatie real axis. Choosing the branch of $f$ such that $f(i)=e^{5\pi}$, compute the value of $f(1+i)$

b) Let log be the function defined by the principal value of the logarithm, Let $Log$ be the branch of the logarithm that satisfies $Im(Log(z)\in (-3\pi/2, \pi/2], \forall z \in \Bbb C$. Express the function $Log$ in terms of $log$.

For a)

My thought was to evaluate $f(i)$ and then just choose a branch $\alpha $that $\alpha \le Arg(f(i)) < \alpha + 2\pi$

The polar form of $-2i$ is $2e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ and because we have a

$$f(i)=i^{-2i}=e^{ilog(2e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}})}=e^{\frac{pi}{2}log(2e)}=\pi e$$

So i believe i made a mistake already....Can someone help me out? And a hint for b) would be very much appreaciated

Comment: What is $F$? You mention $f$ and then ask to compute $F$.

Comment: I can't follow your calculation but suspect you have confused $\alpha^\beta$ and $\beta^\alpha$.

Comment: @johndouma its $f$, i made a typo

Comment: @ancientmathematician yeah i realised i made a mistake there too...

Answer (score 1):

$$f(z)=z^{-2i}=e^{-2i\log z}\implies e^{5\pi}=f(i)=e^{-2i\log i}\implies log (i)=\dfrac {5\pi i}2$$.

So, the branch of $\log$ is $\log z=\log\lvert z\rvert +(\rm{Arg(z)}+2\pi)i$.

Thus $f(1+i)=e^{-2i(\log(1+i))}=e^{-2i(\log\sqrt2 +(\dfrac {9\pi}4)i)}=e^{-2i(\log\sqrt2) +\dfrac {9\pi}2}$.

For $b$, they differ by $- 2\pi i$ for $\rm{Arg}(z)\in(\dfrac \pi2,\pi)$.  Otherwise they're equal, that is, except on their respective branch cuts.

Comment: Thanks i just realised what i did, thou isnt $log(i)=-\frac{5pi}{2i}$? And can you tell me a bit more about that branch please?